# Exclude a combination of characters in Regex (if the combination is found, the regex should fail)

Tags: regex

I am attempting to write a regex to validate a sequence of numbers, and the regex should consist only of numbers- where the only rule is that the numbers 0049 is not allowed to be at the start of the sequence. The sequence is also restricted to only be 10 to 15 characters in length

Examples:

```
0049123456789 - Must Fail
0321123456789 - Allowed to succeed
```

The issue I am facing is that I am unsure how to force-fail the regex if the sequence '0049' is found in the first 4 positions in the character string. Here are some patterns I have tried.

Example number used: 0049123456789

`^(^0049)|^(\d{10,15}+)$` - Matched against 0049, the regex validates as success

`^((?<!(0049))|(\d{10,15}+))$` - both of the regex alternative capturing groups succeeded (`(?<!(0049))` and `(\d{10,15}+)`, validating the entire input as a successful input

`^([^0049])|^(\d{10,15}+)$` - The second capturing group `(\d{10,15}+)` marks the combination of numbers as a success since it conforms to the rule of being numbers only, within a length of 10 - 15 characters.

I have never been any good with regexes - how can I force fail the combination of numbers `0049123456789` - just because `0049` is found at the start of the sequence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
^(?!0049)\d{10,15}$
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mG4oK9/1)

Regex breakdown:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!0049)` - a negative lookahead checking if there is `0049` right after the beginning of string - and if found, **no match is returned**
- `\d{10,15}` - 10 to 15 digits
- `$` - end of string.

Your regexps:

- `^(^0049)|^(\d{10,15}+)$` - Matched against `0049` because you asked it to match `0049` at the beginning of the string (both `^` in `^(^0049)` are start-of-string anchors)
- `^((?<!(0049))|(\d{10,15}+))$` - matches since `^((?<!(0049))` means *match if the start of string is not preceded with `0049`*
- `^([^0049])|^(\d{10,15}+)$` - matches as the 2nd alternative finds a match, you are right. However, note that `[^0049]` is a negated character class matching any character but `0`, `4` and `9` (it does not "negate" a *sequence* of digits).

Comment: oh hell. I did look down this route too, my mistake being that I left the pipe character between `^(?!0049)` and `\d{10,15}$`

Comment: When you use alternation, you allow several possibilities. When you use a lookahead without alternation, you *restrict* the subsequent pattern.

Comment: I learned something today. Heck, you got me excited about regexes. I should really download a couple of regex cookbooks and educate myself more.

Answer (score 3):

[Negative look](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) aheads will be useful here

```
/^(?!0049)[0-9]{10,15}$/
```

- `^` Anchors the regex at the start of the string.
- `(?!0049)` Negative look ahead, checks if the start of the string is ***not*** `0049`
- `$` Anchors the regex at the end of the string

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/iW2kR4/3)

Comment: Good answer, but I will have to mark @stribizhev as correct, since he conformed to the 10 - 15 character restriction.

a good number - 0048123456789123456 - still validated correctly with your regex.

*edit* aaand you changed it.

Comment: @Krohn Yeah, I missed the character limit part :( . Was in a hurry to answer ,didn't read the question completely.